# solve third order scalar using 3 by 3 matrix recursion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, recurrence-relations

Suppose I have something like the following:

$$t(n+2) = 3t(n+1) - 2t(n) + t(n-1)$$

I do not want a complete solution to this question. All that I would like to know is how to convert this into a 3 by 3 matrix. This was my attempt, but it seems to be wrong:

$\begin{bmatrix} t(n) \\ t(n+1) \\ t(n+2)\end {bmatrix}$$=$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0 & 0 \\ 3 & -2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix} t(n-1) \\ t(n) \\ t(n+1)\end{bmatrix}$

Can someone explain how to write it as a 3 by 3 matrix, I can take it from there....

Comment: See [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). **Edit:** It even has an [appropriate section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix#Linear_recursive_sequences) for this kind of problem.

Comment: Don't forget to place $1$'s in the first two rows so that when you do the matrix multiplication, you get $t(n) = t(n)$ and $t(n+1) = t(n+1)$